# How do I evaluate the average memory used while running a certain part of code?

Tags: python, memory

I am working on reducing the amount of memory used by my Python code, therefore I would like to know a time averaged amount of memory used. Is this something doable?

This might sound like a stupid question, but I am so curious and could not find any reference for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using psutil? https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you profile a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: @badri Thanks for telling me that, but I am not sure how to do a time averaged memory use with `psutil `.